# знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Вот дом  Чудный дом  Стоит он в городе большом  А что за люди в нем живут  Что делают  Как их зовут

Answer (score 1):

А мне чудятся восклицания... И столбик стихов...

***Вот дом!***

***Чудный дом!***

***Стоит он в городе большом...***

***А что за люди в нем живут?***

***Что делают?***

***Как их зовут?***

Answer (score 0):

Знаки препинания?

Вариант:

***Вот дом. Чудный дом. Стоит он в городе большом. А что за люди в нем живут? Что делают? Как их зовут?***